# Is it possible to load a database in the RAM?

Tags: mysql

I want to load a MYSQL-database into the RAM of my computer, is there a way to do this? I am running this database under Linux. Also, if this is possible, is there a good way to make backups, because if the computer is unexpectedly shut down, I would lose all my data.

Comment: How to do this in a Windows system?

Answer (score 19):

If you buffer pool is big enough, you data is -- effectively -- an in-memory database with a disk backup copy.  Don't fool around with RAM databases, simply make the buffer pool size as large as you can make it.

Read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use the [MEMORY engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).  As far as backups, it's your call.   You never said, e.g. how often you want to store to disk.  But you can use traditional [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) or your own solution.

Comment: But when you shutdown the Mysqlserver all rows stored in MEMORY tables are lost

Comment: Yes, jitter, that's true.  It's morke's call how to handle that.

Answer (score 5):

absolutely, for example under linux you can mount your database in a [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPFS)

Comment: This could be a viable solution if you are capable of doing regular snapshots to backup the database. Else in case of a crash the DB is lost as on reboot, everything in a tmpfs will be lost

Answer (score 5):

If you're using innodb tables then I recommend adjusting the buffer pool size like S.Lott suggested above.  Make it 110% or so of your database size if you have the ram.

If your database is > 50mb you'll also want to look at increasing the innodb_log_file_size.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size  Perhaps to around 25 - 50% of your buffer pool size, but 1gb max.

The innodb_log_file_size is a bit tricky to adjust.  You need to shut the db down, move the current log files into a backup location, and let mysql recreate them when it's restarted (i.e. after you've changed the values in my.cnf).  Google it and you'll find some answers.